# How to configure the number of combiners in MapReduce?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hadoop2

How to configure the number of combiners in MapReduce?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot configure the number of combiners in Hadoop. The system will automatically determine whether to run them or not. There is no guarantee that they will run at all.

You can configure the logic when to run a combiner [by setting `min.num.spills.for.combine`](https://books.google.de/books?id=Wu_xeGdU4G8C&pg=PA209&lpg=PA209&dq=min.num.spills.for.combine&source=bl&ots=i9vRWDTaXq&sig=1fVX2HLqQAO_ZkKVtMEzIU06z_I&hl=de&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjikOqO9PXaAhWLPFAKHcsVBA0Q6AEIXDAF#v=onepage&q=min.num.spills.for.combine&f=false).

Depending on the version of hadoop, `min.num.spills.for.combine` is deprecated and [has been replaced](https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r2.7.2/hadoop-project-dist/hadoop-common/DeprecatedProperties.html) by `mapreduce.map.combine.minspills`.